# Custom pagination for Boto3 method list_inventory_entries

Tags: python, pagination, boto3

```
ec2_inventory = ssm.list_inventory_entries(
       InstanceId=instance_id, 
       TypeName='AWS:Application', 
       NextToken=next_token)

try:
    inventory_entry = ec2_inventory['Entries']

    for entry in inventory_entry:

        try:
                application_name = entry['Name']
        except:
                application_name = ''

        try:
                application_version = entry['Version']
        except:
                application_version = ''

        try:
                application_type = entry['ApplicationType']
        except:
                application_type = ''

        try:
                installed_time = entry['InstalledTime']
                
        except:
                installed_time = ''

        try:
                architecture = entry['Architecture']
        except:
                architecture = ''

        try:
                application_publisher = entry['Publisher']
        except:
                application_publisher = ''

        try:
                release = entry['Release']
        except:
                release = ''

        try:
                application_url = entry['URL']
        except:
                application_url = ''

        try:
                package_id = entry['PackageId']
        except:
                package_id = ''
```

This method `list_inventory_entries` is paginated for `aws cli`, but `Boto3` does not support pagination and I don't know how to get the next page. The page limit seems to be 50. on the `cli` I do receive next token at the end and the method has an optional parameter `NextToken` but hasn't worked for me yet

Comment: while next_token is not None:

Comment: next_token = ec2_inventory.get('NextToken', None)

Answer (score 1):

According to [list_inventory_entries](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.list_inventory_entries) boto3 documentation there is

1. parameter *MaxResults* by which you limit answers
2. `'NextToken': 'string'` in result which you may use in next call
3. *NextToken (string)* parameter, that is the token for the next set of items to return. You received this token from a previous call and use it in next call.

Comment: MaxResults is used to limit the number of entries returned. I need the full set. I am using NextToken but the issue is when the first call is made with NextToken as None the iteration fails. Can you guide on how to iterate when NextToken is None.
if you see my previous comment I am using while to iterate and after everything is done I am storing NextToken in next_token

Comment: To have clear situation - please edit your code and include `while` and `next_token = ...` in question's code not in question's comments. Please also remove whole `for entry in inventory_entry:` which is the biggest part of your code but not related to the problem,

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked

```
    first_iteration = False
    if next_token == None:

        ec2_inventory = ssm.list_inventory_entries(InstanceId=instance_id, TypeName='AWS:Application')
        next_token = "something"

    while next_token is not None:                
        if first_iteration != False:
            ec2_inventory = ssm.list_inventory_entries(InstanceId=instance_id, TypeName='AWS:Application', NextToken=next_token)
        first_iteration = True
        inventory_entry = ec2_inventory['Entries']
        for entry in inventory_entry:
            try:
                application_name = entry['Name']
            except:
                application_name = ''
                                                                                        
        try:
            next_token = ec2_inventory.get('NextToken')
        except:
            next_token = None
```